# Why does de-serialization of class including reference to self in HashSet fails

Tags: java, serialization, hashset

Why does below program gives NullPointerException.

I tried to get my head around why it is failing but could not understand.

This seems to be due to the cyclic references.

If somebody knows how serialization works internally. Please help.

Link to JDK bug- [JDK-6208166 : De-serialization of class including reference to self in HashSet fails](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do;jsessionid=fa0fe7813b2c05ffffffffb601b012d7a2f56?bug_id=6208166)

```
package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class TestSerialization
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass ();
        byte[] serialized = output (obj);
        Serializable deserialized = input (serialized);
    }

    public static byte[] output (Serializable obj) throws Exception
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream obytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
        ObjectOutputStream ostream = new ObjectOutputStream (obytes);

        ostream.writeObject (obj);
        ostream.flush ();
        byte[] bytes = obytes.toByteArray ();

        obytes.close ();
        ostream.close ();

        return bytes;
    }

    public static Serializable input (byte[] bytes) throws Exception
    {
        ByteArrayInputStream ibytes = new ByteArrayInputStream (bytes);
        ObjectInputStream istream = new ObjectInputStream (ibytes);

        Serializable obj = (Serializable)istream.readObject ();

        ibytes.close ();
        istream.close ();

        return obj;
    }
}

class MyClass implements Serializable
{
    private String m_name = "anything";
    private Set m_set = new HashSet ();

    public MyClass ()
    {
        m_set.add (this);
    }

    public int hashCode ()
    {
        return m_name.hashCode ();
    }
}
```

Comment: What 'JVM bug'? Reference? Citation? Link?

Comment: @EJP upated question.

Comment: Did you read the comments for this bug? There is a workaround listed there.

Comment: @Balder I tried it but it is not working.

Comment: Could you post some example code of your actual program that is not working? Perhaps then a workaround could be found more easily.

Comment: You asked "what is the workaround", where the workaround is clearly listed. Why didn't you ask "how to make the workaround work for me?"

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I will update question later.. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Hi @MarkoTopolnik I updated the question so its more clear.